# Formatting poetry collection and formatting standards

Tags: publishing, formatting, poetry

What does the industry use? I thought about just copy pasting the lyrics into a file format and then appending them in one file, but I am wondering if most publisher use some kind of software to put some motifs on the page borders and things like that to make it more enticing. I am wondering if it's something you need to do, or it's totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You write: "I am wondering if most publisher use some kind of software to put some motifs on the page borders and things like that to make it more enticing. I am wondering if it's something you need to do, or it's totally unnecessary."

This gives me the impression that you write something that you aren't familiar with as a reader. Because your question wouldn't arise if you had seen other books of poetry. Then you would know whether they are decorated or not.

If you are self-publishing, go to a bookstore and look at other books of poetry. You will quickly understand how they are designed.

If want to submit your collection to a publisher, *do not* decorate your manuscript with ornamets. Just submit plain text.